# How to access log from deployed application in Homey

Tags: homey

I have recently published an app on the app store. Some users have reported some issues, but without the logs I am shooting in the dark. Is there a way to retrieve the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user can send you a log by email by going to More > Apps > Your app > Gear icon > Create diagnostics report

Alternatively, you can install the Homey Log (https://athombv.github.io/node-homey-log/) module to send app logs to Sentry.